# Custom errors in forms

Tags: django, forms, error-handling

I'm trying to make a custom error in a form in a class based view (CreateView). I have read the documentation and it is supposed that with the `clean()` function you can add errors, but my problem is that the form is submitted even when the error should appear.

this is my class:

```
class RecommendationCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Recommendation
    template_name = 'recommendation/recommendation_new.html'
    form_class = NewPostForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')


    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        """ Passes the request object to the form class.
         This is necessary to only display members that belong to a given user"""

        kwargs = super(RecommendationCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['request'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs


    def post(self, request):
        super(RecommendationCreateView, self).post(request)
        to_user=request.POST['to_user']
        to_user = user_model.objects.filter(id = to_user).get()
        hobby = request.POST['hobby']
        hobby = Hobby.objects.filter(id = hobby).get()
        recom = Recommendation.objects.create(from_user=request.user, to_user=to_user, hobby=hobby, text=request.POST['text'])
        recom.save()

        return redirect('recommendations')
```

this is my form:

```
class NewPostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        super(NewPostForm, self).clean()
        to_user          = self.cleaned_data.get('to_user')    

        to_user = user_model.objects.filter(username=to_user.username).get()
        
        if to_user.username == 'NAME':
            self._errors['to_user'] = 'Custom error to display'
        return self.cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = Recommendation
        fields = ('from_user', 'to_user', 'hobby', 'text')
        widgets = {'from_user': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

this is my model:

```
    class Recommendation(models.Model):
        
        id = models.UUIDField(
            primary_key = True,
            default = uuid.uuid4,
            editable = False
        )
        from_user = models.ForeignKey(
            get_user_model(),
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            related_name="recommendation_request_sent",
        )
        to_user = models.ForeignKey(
            get_user_model(),
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            related_name="recommendation_requests_received",
        )
        hobby = models.ForeignKey(Hobby, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        text = models.TextField(null = True, blank = True)
    
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('recommendations')
```

My goal is that when I make a recommendation if I send the form with the field "to_user" with the name "NAME" I get a custom error in the form. I enter the function "clean" and enters the if when they are the same but the form is sent anyway.

How can I stop the form from being sent? I have tried other functions like `form_valid()` but it never enters this function.

Comment: you do not throw any validation error, why form wouldn't be considered valid

Comment: how do I make it throw the error?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation

Comment: I do the clean method as indicated in the documentation but it does not give any error.    def clean(self):
    
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        to_user = cleaned_data.get("to_user")
 
        if str(to_user) == "NAME":
        
            raise ValidationError("Custom error display")